# RabbitMQ problems with node on cluster

Tags: rabbitmq, haproxy, high-availability

I have some problems with my RabbitMQ HA cluster.
Problems are next:
I have 3 nodes in cluster.
Node 2 and 3 joined with node 1.
When I have load - it goes to node 1 and almost all RAM is used.
If I switch nodes all load goes to the next node but RAM usage is less than on node 1.
Memory investigations shows that all RAM in this moment is used by RabbitMQ binary, but binary at the same time uses only 1 GB of memory, but allocated 5 GB.
If I switch nodes back - 1 node back uses more RAM than other nodes.
What is the problem in this cases?
Can anybody help me to solve this issue?
If you need more information or screenshots I can send them to you.
RabbitMQ 3.6.10
Erlang 20.3

Traffic to RabbitMQ goes to it via HAProxy on the same server which is RabbitMQ located.

Comment: Start by using the latest RabbitMQ and Erlang.

Comment: Any other ideas? I don't want to update my software, because latest RMQ uses Elixir.

Comment: Why would that matter? You don't have to install Elixir, just Erlang. Elixir is a build-time dependency, not a run-time one. Also, RabbitMQ team members just don't have the time to provide free support for out-of-date versions.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll try to fix this via updating RMQ and Erlang, but I'm not sure that this will solve my problem.

Comment: Once you upgrade, be sure your queue masters are balanced. We have a script to help with that - https://github.com/rabbitmq/support-tools/blob/master/scripts/rebalance-queue-masters. If you still have this issue, search the RabbitMQ documentation for the `background_gc` setting and enable it.